# Difference between 2 datetimes in minutes?

Tags: php, datetime

I got the following code:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$then = new DateTime($accountExists['sub_limit']);

$interval = $then->diff($now);
$hours   = $interval->format('%h'); 
$minutes = $interval->format('%i');
echo  'Diff. in minutes is: '.($hours * 60 + $minutes);
```

which returns the difference between 2 datetimes in minutes. If `then` is `2015-05-31 19:15:31` and `now` is `2015-05-31 19:20:31` it returns 5 minutes. But as soon as the day changes, if `then` changes to `2015-05-30 19:15:31` it still returns 5 minutes when it should be 1445 minutes. Could someone point out my error?

Comment: what value do you get in interval when date changes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because months, years can have an arbitrary number of minutes, you might best want to convert your dates to timestamps (seconds since epoch) so you only have to divide by 60. Fortunately, it's easy to do so:

```
$now = new DateTime('2015-05-31 19:20:31');
$then = new DateTime('2015-05-30 19:15:31');

$seconds = abs($now->format('U') - $then->format('U'));
$minutes = floor($seconds / 60);

print $minutes;
```

Comment: I think that's the best solution OP can get. Why didn't I think of that :) (BTW: If you wrap and `abs()` call around it, it doesn't even makes a difference, which timestamp is bigger)

Comment: Good call! I've added this in the example.

Comment: `$minutes = floor($seconds / 60);` is a bit more semantically correct

Comment: Agreed. Edited the example.

Answer (score 0):

That is because it's a full day. So you have to calculate how many minutes one day is. So this should work for you:

Basically here I just get all `days`, `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` from the interval and multiply them by the multiplier to get minutes out of them.

```
<?php

    //Test data
    $now = "2015-05-30 19:20:31";
    $accountExists['sub_limit'] = "2015-05-30 19:15:31";

    $now = new DateTime($now);
    $then = new DateTime($accountExists['sub_limit']);

    $interval = $then->diff($now);
    $multiplier = ["days" => 60*24, "h" => 60, "i" => 1, "s" => 1/60];
    $minutes = 0;
    $values = array_intersect_key((array)$interval, $multiplier);
    foreach($values as $k => $v)
        $minutes += $v*$multiplier[$k];

    echo  "Diff. in minutes is: " . $minutes;

?>
```

output:

```
Diff. in minutes is: 1445
```